# Need Help to Convert javascript function to C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I need to use this javascript function on my c# code. Can some one help me to convert it?

Original Code:

```
var b64_table = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

function b64_decode(data) {
    var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0, result = [];
    if (!data) { return data; }
    data += "";
    do {
        h1 = b64_table.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h2 = b64_table.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h3 = b64_table.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h4 = b64_table.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        bits = h1 << 18 | h2 << 12 | h3 << 6 | h4;
        o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff;
        o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff;
        o3 = bits & 0xff;
        result.push(o1);
        if (h3 !== 64) {
            result.push(o2);
            if (h4 !== 64) {
                result.push(o3);
            }
        }
    } while (i < data.length);
    return result;
}

function keyCharAt(key, i) {
    return key.charCodeAt(Math.floor(i % key.length));
}

function xor_encrypt(key, data) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(data, function (c, i) {
        return c.charCodeAt(0) ^ keyCharAt(key, i);
    });
}

function xor_decrypt(key, data) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(data, function (c, i) {
        return String.fromCharCode(c ^ keyCharAt(key, i));
    }).join("");
}
```

Code Modified untill now:

```
public string Table = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
public string result;

public string Decode(string data)
{
    string o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits;
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        h1 = Table.IndexOf(data.ElementAt(i++));
        h2 = Table.IndexOf(data[i++]);
        h3 = Table.IndexOf(data[i++]);
        h4 = Table.IndexOf(data[i++]);
        bits = h1 << 18 | h2 << 12 | h3 << 6 | h4;
        o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff;
        o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff;
        o3 = bits & 0xff;

        result += (o1);

        if (h3 != 64)
        {
            result+=(o2);
            if (h4 != 64)
            {
                result+=(o3);
            }
        }
    } while (i < data.Length);



    return result;
}
```

Comment: Both C# and Javascript already have Base64 built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
            string input = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
            string encode = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
            string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encode));
```